# Plural possessive of a family name

Tags: possessives, proper-nouns, surnames

If I want to say that I spent the night at the house that belongs to the Johnsons, which of the following structures is correct:

- *I spent the night at the Johnson's.*

or

- *I spent the night at the Johnsons'.*

Answer (score 3):

It is Johnsons'; because the house doesn't belong to Johnson, but Johnsons.

Answer (score 0):

Either

- I spent the night at <strike>the</strike> Johnson's.

or

- I spent the night at **the** Johnsons'.

The definite article comes in when the reference is the family (**the** Johnsons), rather than the individual (Johnson).